# Include certain .jar for javacv project

Tags: javacv

it's just simple question. Can I include certain .jar files from javacv library for my project? I mean not for all this .jar files.

Thanks before guys. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is no need to add all the `javacv` library files.
Just include the following `jar` files.

```
javacpp.jar
javacv.jar
javacv-linux-x86 (for linux 32bit OS)
javacv-linux-x86_64 (for linux 64 bit OS)
javacv-macosx-x86_64 (for mac OS)
javacv-windows-x86 (for windows 32bit OS)
javacv-windows-x86_64 (for windows 64bit OS)
```